# Why does JSF process the entire form

Tags: jsf, jboss, richfaces, mojarra

We are developing web application using JSF. We are using rich faces on Jboss server. We have a4j command buttons , command links and a4j js functions to invoke server actions.

We have set limit render to true, render only required components. And I also set execute to "@this" . We are observing a strange behavior , All the actions associated with the form are also executed along with the button clicked, even though we have not specified the execute value to "@this". This is bringing down the performance drastically.

Is this the way JSF process POST requests or is there something else we are missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand "processed" in your question. Is your concrete problem that the values of **all** input fields of the HTML `<form>` are been and sent to the server side? (please don't confuse this with "processed"; this is actually not true, only the ones identified by `execute` attribute will be actually processed).

Comment: The behavior we observe is that the component we asked to render on completion of action gets re rendered correctly but if we look at the logs, everything in the form is executed, just as good as the form is reloaded. I am sorry if I am still not clear.

Comment: Replacing "entire form is processed" with "everything in the form is executed" does not make your meaning much clearer. Is every action method of every button invoked? Is the value of every input written to the respective backing bean property? Or are you merely wondering why every component is instantiated?

Comment: Yes meriton, every action method of every button is invoked.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you observed it like that? Aren't you confusing command link/button action methods with JS/ajax/valuechange event listener methods? This is not the normal case. Either there are some serious design mistakes in the view, or there's a major bug in the RichFaces version used (no one comes to mind, though). An SSCCE would be helpful in getting some more technical insight into your situation.

Comment: I re verified the behavior very closely. What I am observing is that the form gets updated on server side every time I change any value in autosuggest or click any commandlink or comandbutton or call a A4j:js function. I dont have any valuechange listeners defined. If this is caused by lauechangelistners that jsf uses, how to suppress them. Sorry could not get a sample code for this.

Comment: Create one then. What you're currently describing in the question is definitely not the default behaviour. Read the last point of *"Information to provide when asking JSF questions"* in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for some hints how to easily create a good example.

Comment: Hi BalusC, the problem was we had written log interceptors. Then I wrote phase interceptors following your blog and it was very evident that the JSF was trying to save the state of entire page which looked as like entire form was getting processed. You have answered my question and I would like to transfer the bounty point. Please can you write a formal conclusion to this , so that I can accept it as solution

Comment: Okay, that clarifies a lot, I have posted an answer. Sorry for the late respons, I didn't notice your comment reply at all until someone else edited your question and brought it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently describing in the question is definitely **not** the default behaviour of JSF nor RichFaces.

Your concrete problem is caused elsewhere. As per the comments, you seem to have created a `PhaseListener` for logging purposes which is re-executing the entire view for some reason. You'd need to turn off this `PhaseListener` or to fix its implementation.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, your blogs helped me a lot in nailing down the issue. I have spawned a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570635/how-to-keep-the-jsf-compnent-tree-size-minimum as continuation to this on a different note and approach.

Comment: Am learning the stack overflow . Thank you for informing me. I have clicked on bounty points and I think you would have got it now. I thought it was automatically transferred :)